# Mongoose model is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

user-controller.js

```js
const uuid = require('uuid')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const saltRounds = 12;

const User = '../models/user'




async function registerUser(req, res, next) {
    const {displayName, password} = req.body;
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)
    const newUser = new User({
        displayName: displayName,
        password: hash,
        uuid: uuid.v4()
    });

    const response = await newUser.save();

    res.json({
        message: "registration success",
        userCreated: newUser
    })
}
```

user.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uuid: {type:String},
    displayName: {type:String},
    password: {type:String}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

error

```
TypeError: User is not a constructor
```

I am really not sure what's going on, i tried different methods of exporting the model. I looked through some other instances of this error occuring and it looks like most of them occur because of incorrect exports. I have another model that I use that works perfectly fine, but when i create it in the user-controller.js it has the same problem as User...

Answer (score 0):

Im just dumb and forgot to import the model correctly!

I did

```js
const User = '../models/user'
```

You need to do

```js
const User = require('../models/user')
```

FACEPALM